# Getting "Sorry, something went wrong with adding the app. Click to retry." when adding a SPFx library to a site

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions

I made a SPFx library component and deployed it to my tenant app catalogue (as a non tenant wide publish). I then tried to add the app to one of my sites but it says `Sorry, something went wrong with adding the app. Click to retry.`. How can I add it, or for this type of app does only tenant wide install work?

EDIT:
I Clicked the elipses and went into errors, clicked the link on Install Errors and got this. This box popped up and then the page went all white, no content.
[image]

Comment: Please click on the elipsis "..." of your app and then click on "Details", then under Error section, click on teh Install Errors link and see what the error is.

Comment: I did that, but it went into a white page with no content.

Comment: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/6496